# Combining group_by and sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, group-by, sum

I have a `model` with the following  attributes:

```
user_id,  week_id,  project_id,  hours
1         61         1             20
1         62         1              5
1         61         2             15
1         63         1              0
2         61         1              0
```

My `view` look like this:

```
<tr>
61 | 62 | 63  (week_id)
35 | 5  | 0   (Sum of hours per week_id)
</tr>

all_hours = Model.group_by(&:user_id)
@all_hours.each do |user, hours| %>
<tr>
hours.each do | hour |
hour.my_hours
```

and gives me two lines of `user 1`

How to group the second time & sum the hours per week_id up to get the wanted result?

To make it more clear (hopefully) :

```
@hours= Model.all.group_by(&:user_id)
<% @hours.each do |user, hours| %>

<tr>
  <% hours.each do |h|%>
      <td><%= h.hours%></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

gives me one long row per user like:
0.0 20.0 0.0 ....  0.0 15.0 0.0
now I want to sum the 20 and the 15
within this line
0.0 35.0 0.0

Answer (score 0):

I would give this a try with rails 3:

```
Model.select(:week_id).
  select(Model.arel_table[:hours].sum.as("sum_of_hours")).select(:user_id)
  group(:week_id).group(:user_id)
```

The library used here is [`arel`](https://github.com/rails/arel) and is part of rails 3, activerecord.

I would assume that this works. But I haven't tried it myself. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried this..thanks..it sums up all hours per week_id. But I need to display these hours per user sum per week_id.

Comment: Because I don't have access to Stackoverflow anymore. For some reason they kicked me out..no idea whymy be that funny point system I don't understand. Thanks for your help..